# How to catch an audio file url issue?

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

I am using audio_service with just_audio and have constructed a minimal example repo using the tutorial code I found in the repo.

If the URL I use to initialize the AudioPlayerHandler is incorrect for any reason (hardcoded in the example code just for illustration purposes, see link below) I am unable to find a way to detect the error. There is an unhandled exception that messes up the state, and I can't figure out how to catch this and take appropriate steps in the app to let the user know there has been an error. Is there a callback or something I can listen to?

https://github.com/SarvagyaVaish/audio_service_bad_url_example/blob/master/lib/audio_player_handler.dart#L13

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: (-1100) The requested URL was not found on this server.
#0      AudioPlayer._load (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:785)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1351)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Doesn't the official just_audio example demonstrate how to do that? Also, doesn't the README page give an example of that?

Comment: Oh, I see. They convert it to an await and wrap it in a try-catch.

For future readers: See the "Catching player errors" section on https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet from the "Catching player errors" section on pub.dev/packages/just_audio

```
try {
  await player.setUrl("https://s3.amazonaws.com/404-file.mp3");
} on PlayerException catch (e) {
  // iOS/macOS: maps to NSError.code
  // Android: maps to ExoPlayerException.type
  // Web: maps to MediaError.code
  // Linux/Windows: maps to PlayerErrorCode.index
  print("Error code: ${e.code}");
  // iOS/macOS: maps to NSError.localizedDescription
  // Android: maps to ExoPlaybackException.getMessage()
  // Web/Linux: a generic message
  // Windows: MediaPlayerError.message
  print("Error message: ${e.message}");
} on PlayerInterruptedException catch (e) {
  // This call was interrupted since another audio source was loaded or the
  // player was stopped or disposed before this audio source could complete
  // loading.
  print("Connection aborted: ${e.message}");
} catch (e) {
  // Fallback for all errors
  print(e);
}
```